# How to use Sqlite for Windows phone 7

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

It seems it is going to be a long wait for SQLCE 4 for WP7. Can anyone guide me on how to install correct version of SQLite and how to use ADO.Net with SQLite for WP7? Any tutorial on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also find [this blog post](http://www.rudigrobler.net/blog/2011/9/27/sqlite-on-wp7.html) by Rudi Grobler useful.